# 12.04 stills shows libre office updates even it is uninstalled

Tags: libreoffice

I uninstalled all libreoffice but the update manager still shows libreoffice updates, (I uninstall it from software center).

How do I remove this updates or remove libreoffice completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice) page says:

> Starting with Ubuntu 11.04, LibreOffice is part of Ubuntu. Since
> LibreOffice is already part of the standard packages.....
> if you're using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, your LibreOffice version is
> 3.5.2. Only security updates will be applied to it, while feature updates for greater versions will be available by using the PPA.

Since it is part of the standard packages and PPA you cannot disable security updates.

Comment: Ok. I will just uncheck the libreoffice updates when applying updates

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources > Other Software* and delete any ppa of libreoffice.
You can also try:
`sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't see any libreoffice specific ppa here